# The mathematical and technical approach to a limit of a sum of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

In Calculus, what is the most preferred mathematical and technical way to approach a limit of a sum of a sequence?
Take for example:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} {\ln(1 + \frac{k}{n})}} $$

Is it a Riemann sum? or is it related to convergence? And what does the limit represent? As a student of Computer Science, I (intuitively) think it represents the actual sum of the sequence, and please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "I (intuitively) think it represents the actual sum of the sequence..." What sequence?

Comment: $a_k = ln(1+ \frac{k}{n})$ is not considered a sequence, my bad.

Comment: $a_k=\log(1+(k/n))$ is a perfectly good sequence, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n)\sum a_k$ does not represent $\sum a_k$.

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , it is the upper Riemann sum with even spaced subintervals --
sample points :$(1+\frac1 {n}) ,(1+\frac2{n}),...,2$ being taken at the right-end because $\ln(x)$ is increasing -- $(1/n)$ being the length of each subinterval.

By continuity of $ \ln(x)$ , as $n\to \infty$ these sums must converge to the integral of $\ln(x)$ over $[1,2] $, which may be computed as follows:

$$I =\int_{1}^{2}  \ln(x) \,\mathrm dx = [x \ln x-x] \Big\vert_{x=1}^{2}=\ln 4-1$$

Comment: i hope it is clear for the OP now , i may further clarify any confusing point..

Comment: Why is the $\frac{k}{n}$ our $x$ and we took the $\frac{1}{n}$ as our $\Delta{x_k}$?

Comment: 1+(k/n) is our $x^*_k$ which  is in the k-th subinterval in our even spaced partition P.To calculate the integral , you could  choose arbitrary sample points in the subintervals and in the limit you get the same integral value.1/n is the length of the subintervals which is generally used for simplicity but we don't have to of course..

Answer (score 2):

More explicitly,
as $k$ goes from
$1$ to $n$,
$\frac{k}{n}$
goes from $0$ to $1$.
Also,
if $x = \frac{k}{n}$,
the spacing between consecutive values of $x$
is $\frac1{n}$,
so the sum, in the limit,
is $\int_0^1 \ln(1+x) dx$,
with $dx$ being $\frac1{n}$.
So this is a Riemann sum
with equally spaced points.

Evaluating this integral,
as Halil Duru did,
$\int_0^1 \ln(1+x) dx
= \int_1^2 \ln(x) dx
= (x \ln x - x)|_1^2
= (2 \ln 2 - 2)-(1 \ln 1 - 1)
= \ln 4 - 1
$.

Comment: I feel like your explanation for the Riemann sum needs to be slightly better made - for example, why are we summing the values of $\ln(1+\frac{k}{n})$ rather than $\ln(1+x)$ for some $ x \in [\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}]$?

Comment: Because that was the sum in the problem. Your more general form will, as a Riemann sum, also converge as a Riemann integral to the value given.