# Determining $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n\cos(\frac{\pi k}{2n})$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \log(1+\frac kn)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Determine

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right) \qquad\text{and}\qquad 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \log\left(1+\frac kn\right)$$

**Attempt**

In the first one I started by noticing that $-1/n \leqslant \frac 1n \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)\leqslant 1/n$, but $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/n$ is divergent, right?

Comment: These are just Riemann sums, i.e. in the limit $n\to\infty$ the sums represent integrals like $$\int_0^1\ln (1+x)\,dx$$

Comment: The first one has been answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2270899/42969, and the second one has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/362348/42969.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx.$$

The first sum is $$\int_0^1 \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)dx=\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\cdot\frac 2π \right]_0^1= \frac 2π $$ and the second sum is $$\int_0^1 \ln(1+x)dx= \int_1^2 \ln(u )du$$ (substituting 1+x=u) $$=[u\ln u-u]_1^2=2\ln 2-1=\ln 4-1.$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$
For the first one:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})dx=\frac{2}{\pi}$$
For the second one:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \log\left(1+\frac kn\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\log(x+1)dx=2\log2-1$$

Comment: Isn't that integral over $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: Yes! Just edited